# longClickable on gallery item

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-widget

What I would like to achieve is for the user to longclick on an image in gallery view to take them to a website.

what I have so far is this but can't seem to work it out....

```
 .......
 public int getCount() {
    return imageIDs.length;
 .....
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null){
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);


    }else{
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
    return imageView;

        imageView.setOnLongClickListener(imageIDs[position]){

            boolean onLongClick(int position,View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse ("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    {
    }
}

 }
```

Getting this error

```
 The method setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener) in the type View is not applicable  for the arguments 
 (Integer)
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong. imageIDs[position] returns an int, whereas setOnLongClickListener takes an OnLongClickListener. Something like:

```
imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse ("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Note: Switched OnItemLongClickListener to OnLongClickListener

Comment: Thanks for the reply still no luck though, still gives me the same error.

Comment: I suppose what I could try to do is to have the website address in the text but mask it ie. when user clicks on "example" in the text it will take them to http://www.google.com  So in other words hide the uri and only display "example". Question is ho to do that?

Comment: @Keithk I changed my answer to use an OnLongClickListener instead of OnItemLongClickListener. Had copied the wrong code. Try that and see if it works